# Repository Factory with Ninject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

In my application, I use repositories for CRUD operations. Out of all entities, some should not be deletable at all, some entities (that implement `ISoftDeletable`) are only soft deletable and some entities (that implement `IPermanentDeletable`) can be permanently deleted. (I'm following the answer on this post [Generic Repository with Soft Delete Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299597/generic-repository-with-soft-delete-feature))

I have 3 Repositories that Inherit from one another as follows

```
BaseRepository : IRepository

SoftDeleteRepository : BaseRepository, ISoftDeleteRepository

PermanentDeleteRepository : BaseRepository, IPermanentDeleteRepository
```

My problem is, I don't want to do individual binding for each of the entities of different types like

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<Company>)).To(typeof(BaseRepository<Company>));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<Country>)).To(typeof(PermanentDeleteRepository<Country>));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<Contact>)).To(typeof(SoftDeleteRepository<Contact>));
```

But instead, I want to somehow make it so that all the bindings for `IRepository` go to a factory and instantiate the repository depending on the type of the entity that its generic parameter has taken, and inject it to the controller.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is how you could achieve it while still injecting `IRepository<XYZ>` into the consumer:

```
public interface ISoftDeletable
{
}

public interface IPermanentDeleteable
{
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
}

public class PermanentDeletableRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : IPermanentDeleteable
{
}

public class SoftDeletableRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : ISoftDeletable
{
}

public class RepositoryModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .To(typeof(PermanentDeletableRepository<>))
            .When(IsRequestForRepositoryOfEntityImplementing<IPermanentDeleteable>);

        this.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .To(typeof(SoftDeletableRepository<>))
            .When(IsRequestForRepositoryOfEntityImplementing<ISoftDeletable>);
    }

    public static bool IsRequestForRepositoryOfEntityImplementing<TInterface>(IRequest request)
    {
        Type entityType = GetEntityTypeOfRepository(request.Service);
        return ImplementsInterface<TInterface>(entityType);
    }

    public static Type GetEntityTypeOfRepository(Type repositoryType)
    {
        // target.Type must be IRepository<"AnyEntity">
        return repositoryType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
    }

    public static bool ImplementsInterface<TInterface>(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(TInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }
}
```

I verified with a unit test that it works:

```
    public class SomeSoftDeletableEntity : ISoftDeletable
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void RepositoryBinding()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load<RepositoryModule>();

        IRepository<SomeSoftDeletableEntity> repository = kernel.Get<IRepository<SomeSoftDeletableEntity>>();

        repository.Should().BeOfType<SoftDeletableRepository<SomeSoftDeletableEntity>>();
    }
```

Comment: regarding `public override void Load()`. what if I have other types of repositories as well? As in, any entity that doesn't implement either `ISoftDeletable` or `IPermanentDeletable` that should use `BaseRepository`. To achieve this, is it enough to call base.Load() as the first thing within the Load method we override?

Comment: Sorry, the code i posted is somewhat incomplete. The Load method should be part of a `Module : NinjectModule` which is then loaded by `IKernel.Load<Module>()`. You could also create the bindings with `IKernel.Bind(...)` - it doesn't matter. For your question about the "other" entitites: you should create a third binding, a default binding: `IBindingRoot.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(BaseRepository<>));`. When there are multiple bindings, ninject will use one with a `.When(...)` before using one without.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works as I wanted.